# Scala Sealed trait def to val (How to set value?)

Tags: java, scala, sbt, traits, scala-2.10

I'm kinda new to Scala and have been working on a piece of code that looks like this:

```
sealed trait Bank {
   def branch: Option[BranchName]
}
case object Bank {
  case class SomeBank(details: BankDetails)
  extends Bank {
    // NEED TO SET BRANCH HERE IN A VAL
    val branch = ???
  }
}
```

I'm kinda confused about how to set the branch variable which is defined as a `def` in the trait. When I debug I'd like to see `branch` as a property of the class so its be can be called as :`SomeBank.branch` because other services depend on `branch` as a property of the `case class SomeBank`.

The `BranchName` that is required as a return is another case class with bunch of details in it.

One hacky way of how I did it is by adding an extra parameter to case class:

```
case class SomeBank(details: BankDetails, setBranch: Option[BranchName]) 
extends Bank { val branch = setBranch }
```

However, this is bad because `SomeBank` basically has 2 properties that are duplicate i.e setBranch and branch are exactly the same. What would be the best way to do this so that I can just have `branch` set to what I want?

Comment: have you tried `case class SomeBank(foo: Bar, branch: Option[BranName])`?

Comment: `final case class SomeBank(details: Bank Details, branch: Option[Branch])`? - Although, it sounds like you want an `object` rather than a `class`

Comment: Yep! That worked great. Had no idea override methods can directly be added under class parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case classes are good for modeling immutable data so keep in mind `branch` should be an immutable `val` under the case class `SomeBank`.

You can define `branch` directly (`override val` is optional):

```scala
case class SomeBank(
  details: BankDetails, 
  override val branch: Option[BranchName]
) extends Bank
```

Comment: The `override val` isn't necessary in a case class, because all parameters to a case class' constructor/apply are `val` by default and `override` is a sort of optional keyword in Scala.

Comment: This is the correct solution to his question. However,  `override` is not optional in Scala. The rule says that the `override` keyword is required for all member that override a concrete implementation in a parent class and optional if a member implements an abstract member with the same name. Since he is not overriding any concrete definition, it is optional in this case indeed, but for better clarity and safety, you can keep it (the compiler will detect if you misspell `branch`). `val` is also optional indeed, but `override` alone will not compile, that is why he wrote `override val`.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I needed. thank you. Works fine without the `override` keyword as mentioned above. There's so many caveats to Scala but it's exciting!